# Is it OK to update a production database with EF migrations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-schema, entity-framework-migrations

According to [this blog post](http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/) most companies using EF Migrations are supposedly not updating the database schema of production databases with EF migrations. Instead the blog post's author recommends to use Schema update scripts as part of the deployment process.

I've used Schema update scripts for a few years now and while they work, I was planning to use EF migrations instead in the future for the following reasons:

- Faster deployment, less downtime
- A simpler deployment procedure
- Much easier migration of existing data than it would be possible with T-SQL
- A more comprehensible syntax of the changes waiting to be applied (DbMigration class with clean C# syntax vs. clunky T-SQL Migration script in a traditional environment).
- There is an easy and fast downgrade path to the old db schema if the deployment of the new software version should fail

One reason I can think of that would prohibit the use of EF to migrate a production DB would be if the DB schema was only altered by the DBAs as opposed to the Developers. However, I am both DBA and Developer, so this does not matter in my case.

So, what are the risks of updating a production database using EF?

Edit: I would like to add that, as solomon8718 already suggested, I am always pulling a fresh copy of the production database to my staging server and test the EF Migrations to be applied on the staging server before applying them to a production server. IMO this is essential for any schema update to a production system, whether I'm using EF migrations or not.

Comment: I'm not a fan of EF, but I'm also not a fan of DBAs 'checking' my table alterations! this puts me in a quandary. Do I trust EF with my live system? NO! do I want to write a billion crappy schema update scripts? NO!

Comment: create table genericTable varchar(max) xmldatacol to the rescue!

Comment: @Ewan: Unless you are using Automatic Migrations (which I am not), you do get something very similar to a T-SQL schema migration script as part of the generated DbMigration class. You can see each alteration in detail. IMO it's also much easier to check for validity than T-SQL since it's easier to comprehend than SQL syntax.

Comment: What about sprocs? if a helpful DBA has written some sproc or trigger or something which is not part of my data model in EF, but which does reference it?

Comment: @Ewan: You can run standard T-SQL commands as part of your migration. So if you want (or need to, in the case of sprocs) you could just as well use a single (or several) t-sql scripts instead / as part of your migration procedure.

Comment: What if the helpful DBA has made changes to the DB. ie your local db is out of date?

Comment: It depends on the changes the DBA makes. There are of course infinite amounts of schema alterations that would render your app unoperational. But the same could be said about an app that does not use EF Migrations at all. Only exception: Changes to the __MigrationHistory table. If the DBA would mess with that, then the app could not correctly determine the migrations that still have to be run. All kinds of things could go wrong then. But then again, if you mess with the schema and don't know what you are doing, you can always break any app.

Comment: Mason: I am not looking to advertise any opinion here, I am asking for points I might have missed because I don't understand what the blog post I linked to is talking about. It would seem that the 7 people who upvoted my post before you would also agree that this an interesting topic, especially those four that even starred it.

Comment: @AdrianGrigore, I can see where you're coming from, but I think maybe the question should be worded differently. 'Is there any good reason' does sound like a subjective question. It's also difficult to answer; I don't think you could ever definitively answer it with 'No', but 'Yes, here are some reasons...' would probably use subjective reasons that are dependent on a particular risk strategy.  A better way to ask might be something like 'What are the risks of updating a production database using EF?' For the record I'm interested in the answer too.

Comment: I agree, please keep this open,  even if doesn't 100% comply with SO rules, it is indeed a very interesting question.

Comment: Retracting my close vote, since it seems to comply with [the information](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) contained in the help center where subjective questions are allowed in certain circumstances.

Comment: The main reason I don't use Code First / Migrations in production is that your user requires sa permissions. This is obviously a big security risk in a lot of environments. If you are comfortable with this or happy to temporarily grant those permissions then why not?

Comment: DrewJordan: Thanks for the hint. I apologize if it sounded too confrontational, I am not a native English speaker and my native language (German) does tend to be a bit more direct than English... :)

Comment: disadvantages imply that you need to know the exact circumstances everything is running in in order to know if it applies; risks can apply universally.  Removed 'disadvantage' from the text so as not to invite closure because it would be "Primarily opinion based".  It still may be too broad ("Give me a list of risks for X").

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Well, I'll try and answer anyhow. I would say No, there's no reason not to use Code First Migrations in production. After all, what's the point of this easy to use system if you can't take it all the way?

The biggest problems I see with it are all problems that you can have with any system, which you've noted already. As long as the whole team (DBA included if applicable) is on board with it, I think allowing EF to manage the schema through migrations is less complex, and hence less error-prone than traditional script-based management. I would still take a backup before performing a migration on a production system, but then you'd do that anyhow.

There's nothing that says a DBA can't perform a migration from Visual Studio, either. The access could still be locked down with privileges at the database level, and he/she could review the migration (in a helpful SQL export format using `-Script`, if desired) before performing the actual operation. Then they're still in control, but you can use code-first migrations. Hell, they might even end up liking it!

Update: since SPROCs and TVFs were brought up, we handle those in migrations as well, although they are actually done with straight-up SQL statements using a `DbMigration.Sql()` call in the `Up()`, and the reverse of them in the `Down()` (You can also use `CreateStoredProcedure` and `DropStoredProcedure` for simple SPROCs, but I think you still have to define the body itself in SQL). I guess you could say that's a caveat; there isn't yet a way for an entire, comprehensive database to be written purely in C#. However, you *can* use migrations which include SQL scripts to manage the entire schema. One benefit we've found from this process is you can use the C# config file for schema object names (different server names for production vs dev for example) with a simple `String.Format`, combined with XML Transformation for the config files themselves.

Comment: For creating SP's and Functions we use DbMigration.Sql() which works locally fine. Though after deployment (VSTS) the SP's are created but the migration record isn't created. Checking the drop/sql shows that the insert are there.
Locally everything is fine and the migration recs are created.
Any ideas? Not very keen to add them manually on all azureDB's....

Answer (score 42):

Yes there are good reasons **not** to use an automated system such as Code First Migrations to make *production* database changes. But as always there are exceptions to the rules.

1. One reason which has been mentioned would be access permissions, which would be directly related to your organization's change management rules and security policies.
2. Another reason would be your level of trust in the Migrations tool itself. Are we sure the tool doesn't have a bug in it? What happens if the tool fails midway through? Are you certain you have up-to-date backups and a process to roll-back if need be?
3. The change scripts may execute unexpected or inefficient scripts. I've experienced cases where the sql generated copied the data into a temp table, dropped the original table, then recreated the original table for things like adding a new column if you accidentally (or purposefully) change the order in which the column appears, or when you rename the table. If millions of records are involved this could cause serious performance issues.

### My recomendation:

Assuming you have a Staging database that mirrors your production schema, use the Migrations tool to generate its change scripts against that system. We usually restore our stage database from a fresh production copy before running. We then examine the change scripts manually to check for issues. After that we run the scripts against our stage database to make sure it executes properly and that all the changes expected took place. Now we are sure that the scripts are both safe to run in production and perform the expected changes. This process would address all three issues I listed above.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive reply. Great point regarding the staging database with a fresh copy of the production database. I have been using the same procedure already, and I would also recommend it.

Comment: "restore our stage database from a fresh production copy" FYI this is known as "pre-production testing"

Comment: Glad to help! In our case we have a database project in Visual Studio rather than an EF project but both use Sql Server Data Tools. I've been on our application deployment team for quite some time now so have experienced some of the issues involved.
@AaronLS - Thanks for the tip

Comment: @solomon8718 How do you get your changes generated from EF migrations into your SSDT project?  If answer is involved I can post new question. I liked SSDT, but among all the ways I could try and keep it sync'd with EF Code First, I never found a way that wasn't too clunky.

Comment: @AaronLS - I haven't come across your problem as our scenario doesn't actually involve EF, but my answer should apply since I believe both suffer from the same issues i listed. But it seems to me that a project should probably elect to track database changes in only one system. It sounds like you're attempting to do both Code-First and Database-First causing your management issue.

Comment: @solomon8718 Agreed, however while you can call SP/TVF from EF, you can't define them in EF. Code First is great for defining structure, SSDT is great for defining TVF and SP's.  It's impossible to make EF the authoritative source of your DB structure if you need to write SP/TVF. So I wanted a workflow of 1) Define/add tables in EF code first, 2) Update SSDT with new structure, 3) Write SP/TVF in SSDT 4) Diff/Generate scripts from SSDT.  #2 is the klunky part, it can be done but it's awkward. I'll post as a separate question one day when I can think about defining the problem well.

Comment: @solomon8718: You can generate an sql script from an existing migration. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#sql for the details.

Comment: @AdrianGrigore - Right, and that's the method I would use. Generate the script, analyze it, then run the generated script against your databases using SSMS or Visual Studio. That's my preferred method as opposed to telling the tool to run the migration directly on the database.

Comment: @AdrianGrigore - I thought of one other potential issue if running the tool directly against a stage database, then a production database. You can't be certain that the generated SQL running against the two database are the same, which is why I recommend generating once against a restored stage database.

Comment: @solomon8718: What do you mean by "You can't be certain that the generated SQL running against the two database are the same"? AFAIK DbMigration class code is the bit that defines what the migration does, hence it should always do the same unless I alter the DbMigration and recompile. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Adrian Grigore - Well the Sql is generated by a comparison engine. As I understand it, SSDT compares the database model in the code to the model on the database to generate the migration script. Can you be absolutely sure you're environments will always match every release? Can you be absolutely sure the comparison engine will always generate the same script? I contend not, and running it only once is the only way to be sure.

Comment: @solomon8718: AFAIK the Sql is *not* generated by a comparison engine . instead, creating the migration creates a DbMigration class, which is is the equivalent of a T-SQL migration script. This is Ä*not* done at runtime, it's done when you create the migration via the Package Manager Console. The migration script is baked in at design time, just as if you would create a regular T-SQL script manually by other means. Are you perhaps mixing up "regular" Migrations with the more exotic Automatic Migrations feature?

Comment: @AdrianGrigore - I fully admit that my experience is with SSDT and the Database project, not EF Migrations and I could be entirely wrong about the use of a comparison engine, but I don't think so. If it didn't use a comparison engine it would have to assume the database is in a particular state, and the migration would fail if the database was not. I found this line in the link you posted: "Code First Migrations will compare the migrations in our Migrations folder with the ones that have been applied to the database. It will see that the AddBlogUrl migration needs to be applied, and run it.".

Comment: @AdrianGrigore - Here is that link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#generating - P.S. SSDT does use a comparison engine, and I suspect that EF migrations and the database project likely share components.

Comment: Well that's dumb. @solomon8718 refers to me.

Comment: @Brian: Sorry, but you are mistaken. What the article you linked to means is that it will look at the data stored in the __MigrationHistory table to determine the current state of the Db before applying the migration. It does *not* mean that it looks at the schema. Looking at the schema is done *only* at design time. In other words: If the _MigrationHistory says that the Db is in a certain state, then EF Migrations will simply assume that this is correct. It does not verify whether or not the DB's schema matches the state stored in the _MigrationHistory table.

Comment: @AdrianGrigore - If you are in charge of your change management by all means, work out the process that works best for you. Personally if what you say is true then that is even more reason for me to not want to use EF Migrations to update my database directly. I don't trust that my database will never change outside of the EF model. And if it does trying to update to the new model could turn into a nightmare with EF failing to complete the update because it expected an object where there was none or vice-versa.

Comment: You can do "update-database -script" to generate the SQL that will be executed, rather than use this method of comparing two databases.

Comment: Right, however that doesn't change the fact that EF generates inferior sql scripts. Like I mentioned before, EF creates a temp table, transfers data to it, then drops and recreates the original table just for things like adding a column. Imagine doing this to a database of millions or hundreds of millions of records. This just isn't at all practical in an enterprise setting.

Answer (score 9):

One other caveat I found: If you have several websites using the same data context, you need to make sure that all of them are updated at the same time. Otherwise there might be a constant database update / downgrade fight between the websites. Other than that, it worked fine for me.

**EDIT: My own perspective one year after starting to use EF Migrations in production:**

EF Migrations is actually pretty cool, even for production use, provided that you

1. Test the migrations on a staging system. I test all migrations by migrating all the way down and up again on my CI server before running integration tests.
2. Do not trigger migrations automatically, but with a batch file that is launched by an admin. This is essentially the same as running the sql for a migration manually in SSMS.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. If answer is not involved, how do you manage the migration code in web app (which should have limited privileges on DB) to alter the schema in DB (which should require higher privileges) ?

Answer (score 4):

I use it in production for a couple of projects. Once you get the hang of it I think it's fine.

During development you can keep auto migrations on but at the end you can connect to the live db right from package manager console and generate a migration. It will give you one migration for all the changes.

But always always always use the `-script` option with `update-database` and fire the SQL yourself.

I would also advice not using the update db option from web deploy. That way there is no way to tell how much of the migration has already been fired on error. I've ran into trouble with that a few times. So best to get the SQL and fire it manually.

Comment: Where does update-database come from ?