# Entity Framework 6 automatic migration on prodiction

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, msbuild, entity-framework-6

I use MSBuild.exe and bat-files to build solution on production.
How I should migrate database on production using Entity Framework 6?
I think that is not cool use this code on prodiction

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a database migration at compile-time?

Comment: I try to run db update on Post-build event command line and from bat-file.

Comment: You want to modify your production database every time you compile your project?

Comment: No, I will modify my production DB once a week. The problem is that I do not have VisualStudio on production, only MSBuild, and I can not run Update-Database on NuGet cmd.
I want to run the script on command line and see the result(errors log or success message). But I do not know how to do this with EF6

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746937/is-it-ok-to-update-a-production-database-with-ef-migrations