# How to get appsettings from project root to IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation in ASP.NET Core 2.0 and EF Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

I am building an application in ASP.NET Core 2.0 and I am having problems with EntityFramework Migrations.

I have my DbContext in a separate project (*SolutionName*\*ProjectNamePrefix*.Data) and therefore I created an implementation for the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory interface.

I wanted to use different connection strings for different environments and I need `appsettings.json` for that.

So after a quick search I found that I can create a new `IConfigurationRoot` object inside the `CreateDbContext` function as shown here:
https://codingblast.com/entityframework-core-idesigntimedbcontextfactory/

I added that and then for testing, tried to run `dotnet ef migrations list -c MyContext` from the Data project root folder.

Then I got the following error:

```
The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'C:\dev\*SolutionName*\*ProjectNamePrefix*.Data\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\appsettings.json'.
```

So, basically, I tried 3 options for getting the correct root path:

- `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();`
- `env.ContentRootPath;` (`IHostingEnvironment` object, I found a way to get it here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2194)
- `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;`

and all of them returned the same `..\bin\debug\netcoreapp2.0\` path. When I run the Data project from VS, then the two first options give me the correct project root folder.

**Is there a way to get the correct project content root folder?**

Because when I added --verbose to the EF command, it logged out a row:

```
Using content root 'C:\dev\FitsMeIdentity\FitsMeIdentity.Data\'.
```

So I understand that EF somehow knows the project root but all the options mentioned above return the path for the already built application.

The only option I found that works is that I change `Copy output to root folder` to `Copy always` but found from here: https://www.benday.com/2017/02/17/ef-core-migrations-without-hard-coding-a-connection-string-using-idbcontextfactory/ that it's not a good idea.

At first I even thought about creating a Constructor for the IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation which gets IOptions as a parameter but that didn't work, had the same problem as explained here:
[Injecting Env Conn String into .NET Core 2.0 w/EF Core DbContext in different class lib than Startup prj & implementing IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085500/injecting-env-conn-string-into-net-core-2-0-w-ef-core-dbcontext-in-different-cl)

Answer (score 14):

A little late, but here is the solution for those who hate hard-coding connections strings:

```
internal class MigrationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>
{
    public AppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
            .Build();
        
        string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext> optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString,
            ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString),
            mySqlOptions =>
                mySqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: 10,
                    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
                    errorNumbersToAdd: null));

        return new AppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding AddEnvironmentVariables and AddCommandLine so the configuration is more like the generic host.

Comment: He's looking to parse appsettings.json. I'm not sure how AddEnvironmentVariables and AddCommandLine will help.

Comment: Also works with AddUserSecrets().

Comment: How do u consume it

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't do this, and more to the point: you're not *supposed to do this*. The whole entire point of `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` is that it's a way to get a `DbContext` instance from in a context where there is no ASP.NET Core framework to work with, i.e. from a class library. If you're running migrations from an ASP.NET Core project, you don't need it, and if you're not, none of the configuration stuff is available.

Additionally, it's only to be used for *development*, hence the "DesignTime" part of the name. As a result, there's no need for stuff like switching between connection strings for different environments. Just hard-code the connection string as the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-idesigntimedbcontextfactorytcontext) detail.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Okay, maybe I'm missing something from the big picture then. What is the intended way to apply EF migrations to Staging/Production environments? I shouldn't use `Update-Database` but instead should I use `Script-Migration` to get the SQL scripts and run them manually every time?

Comment: Yep. That, or some other method of creating versioned migrations, such as ReadyRoll or similar products. You could also create a database project instead. Long and short, there's many different ways to get database changes to production. Just find something that works for your needs.

Comment: I'm confused. I thought that Entity Framework is a tool for end-to-end database management. Quoting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29755781/1616049): `What's the point of this easy to use system if you can't take it all the way?` It doesn't make sense to me to use a third party tool for production DB deployment. Or at least not paid tools. And it's explicitly said on ReadyRoll's website that: `Please note that ReadyRoll's integration with Entity Framework CodeFirst is evolving and may not be suitable for production use.` I will look into DbUp meanwhile but it seems to be added complexity.

Comment: Entity Framework is just an ORM. It is not and never claimed to be a be all, end all, end to end solution for everything you'd ever need to do with a database. Production deployment is a *process*. There should be change management policies and in most Enterprise situations, you'd never be able to get a EF migration within spitting distance of a production database anyways.

Comment: You can access `appsettings.json` configuration in your `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` implementation this way - see my answer for [Injecting Env Conn String into .NET Core 2.0 w/EF Core DbContext in different class lib than Startup prj & implementing IDesignTimeDbContextFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53924899/804385)