# Have DbContext Dependency Injection available in Class library project. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, connection-string, asp.net-core-2.1

In an Asp.Net Core MVC based application, we know that Dependency Injection (DI) is defined right in *Startup* class under *ConfigureServices* method like so:

```
var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

And then we can make use of this DI in Controller via constructor like so:

```
public class BlogsController : Controller
{
    private readonly BloggingContext _context;

    public BlogsController(BloggingContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Blogs
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Blog.ToListAsync());
    }
}
```

But in a real project in order to achieve separation of concerns, we make use of Business Logic Layer (BLL) and create separate project for it. Similarly there is also a Data Abstraction Layer (DAL) which contains all the stuff needed to communicate with the backend Database.

1. So in our case can we access this Dependency Injection in BLL like so ?

```
    public class MyClassLib
    {
        private readonly BloggingContext _context;

        public MyClassLib(BloggingContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
```

2. Also we need to do scaffolding against an existing database and as such DbContext class will be created in DAL project. *OnConfiguring* method will be defined in this created DbContext class. Here connection string is hard coded in class.

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
         if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
         {
             optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=TestDB;user id=sa;password=abcxyz");
         }
    }
```

But can we declare Connection string in our UI MVC project in some json file and access this same connection string in DAL with in our DbContext class ?

Comment: 1: Yes, DI works fine over assembly borders. Be sure to register `MyClassLib`

Comment: 2: Do a normal configure in Startup and the `if(!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)` won't fire.

Comment: @bommelding What do you mean by normal configure?

Answer (score 0):

In Startup.cs class, you find ctor with IConfiguration parameter. You can read json and convert to object with Get<> method. You must add **Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration** package to use this extension method.

In the simplest way, when you read connections, you can set it to a static class property. So I created **ConfigurationManager** class like in good old days.

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings = Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").Get<Dictionary<string, string>>();
    }
```

ConfigurationManager static class:

```
public static class ConfigurationManager
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
}
```

Now, we have a ConfigurationManager object with connections and can use this anywhere we want. Let's call it in your **OnConfiguring** method:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
     if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
     {
         optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["connectionStringName"]);
     }
}
```

If you wonder appSettings.json file:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "yourConnectionName": "Data Source=ConnectionStrings goes here",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can declare connection strings in your UI MVC project json file and access this same connection string in DAL, using and inject `IConfiguration` in the constructor (similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45109353/422877)).

But note it can [not be done for `CreateDbContext`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47054063/how-to-get-appsettings-from-project-root-to-idesigntimedbcontextfactory-implemen?rq=1).
If you want to use it for adding *migrations* to your DAL, you have to somehow point out the startup project and the migrations project, like illustrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55066399/422877).